# Python result Code 0

Tags: python

Hi i have this issue i am executing a shell command in my python script and the probleme i am getting two results instead of 1.
The first is the id that i want to store the second is a 0 and i guess its the result code.

This is my code

```
import os
cmd = "/path/to/ctl so list | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'" 
event_id = os.system(cmd) 
print(event_id)
```

and this is the result:

```
225
0
```

how can i delete that 0.

Thanks

Comment: The quick answer is: don't print it; you've saved the *return code* of `os.system()` into `event_id`; that is `0`. The output of the command you ran showed up as well.  Did you intend to capture the output of the command into `event_id`?

Comment: i just want to retrieve the output without the return code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess is correct that `0` is the return code from your shell command. `os.system(cmd)` is executing your command and outputting the result, and then the return code is stored in `event_id` and printed.

You should use the `subprocess` module instead.

```
import subprocess
cmd = "/path/to/ctl so list | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'" 
event_id = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).rstrip()
print(event_id)
```

Comment: the command is working but I am receiving value along with empty line

Comment: @AkdimKarim, See my edit. Appending `rstrip()` to `event_id` in the print command will strip all trailing whitespace.